# Jquery - How to put the id of each DIV.section as Anchor # on in Each li> a href?

Tags: jquery, text, each, attr

I am trying to get ID from `.section` divs and put in sequence for each `li > a` as `href` anchor '#', and get value text from `.section > h3` put in `li > a` corresponding to `.section ID`.

HTML (rendered):

```
<div id="tabs_wrap">
  <ul> 'Js render list here' </ul>
</div>
<div class="section sc-01" id="title01">
  <h3>Title-01</h3>
</div>
<div class="section sc-02" id="title02">
  <h3>Title-02</h3>
</div>
<div class="section sc-03" id="title03">
  <h3>Title-03</h3>
</div>
<div class="section sc-04" id="title04">
  <h3>Title-04</h3>
</div>
<div class="section sc-05" id="title05">
  <h3>Title-05</h3>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.section h3').text(function() {
  $(this).parents().eq(0).attr('id', $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w ]+/g, '').replace(/ +/g, '').substring(0, 14));
});


var secH3 = $('.section h3').each(function() {
  $(this).text();
});
var secId = $('.section').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('id');
});

$('.section').each(function() {
  $('#tabs_wrap ul').append('<li><a></a></li>');
});

$('#tabs_wrap ul > li a').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('href', '#' + secH3);
});
```

Comment: Since none of the `.section` divs have IDs, I haven't the slightest idea what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Note the js / jquery code, where it generates a list corresponding to each existing div.section the page. look this http://codepen.io/AdsonCicilioti/pen/rVMEKQ?

Comment: So, you want to make a list of contents, with links, to take the user to the relevant section?

Comment: Yep @David Thomas. But in tabs system. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H,
i think you just need this

```
   //Let's loop on all the sections
$('.section').each(function(){
      var label = $(this).find('h3').html(); // we find the h3 tag on each sectin
      var id = $(this).attr('id');//we find the id of each section
      // then we build the li tag within the a tag inside with the dynamic var label and id we just created.
      $('#tabs_wrap ul').append('<li><a href="#'+id+'">'+label+'</a></li>');
 });
```

see http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPGXNK

Comment: Nice!! Its works!  Thx!

I used .text instead .html, but all works fine.

Comment: @david-thomas,  my intention is a dynamic relationship to a navigation system in tabs. I'm trying to create the appropriate markup for that.

Comment: Works fine here: http://codepen.io/AdsonCicilioti/pen/rVMEKQ. Thank u @Oliver Rodomond

Comment: So I saw, thanks. Though I'd argue that `this.id` would be less wasteful/expensive than re-invoking jQuery to find the attribute-value.

Comment: Hey @david-thomas, How to use this.id this case??

Comment: @Adson: simply replace `var id = $(this).attr('id');` with `var id = this.id;`